# python: How to mock os.statvfs as it returns posix.statvfs_result datatype

Tags: python, python-mock

I am trying to write a unit test case Below is the partial code of the original function:

```
def disk_space(something, otherthing):
    """
    Comments
    """
    dir_map = something['dir_map']
    for dir, expected_free_gb in dir_map.items():
        try:
            result = os.statvfs(dir)
            block_size = result.f_frsize
            avail_blocks = result.f_bavail
            giga = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
            free_size = avail_blocks * block_size / giga
            if free_size >= float(expected_free_gb):
                print "No need to clear space"
            else:
                print "Clear some space"
```

Unit Test Function:

```
@patch('os.statvfs', return_value=posix.statvfs_result(f_frsize=4096, f_bavail=2599495))
def test_disk_space(self, os_statvfs):
    something
    something
```

Now here, if I return value in `posix.statvfs_result` data type, it gives the error:

> TypeError: Required argument 'sequence' (pos 1) not found

And if I just give `return_value=(f_frsize=4096, f_bavail=2599495)` it says:

> str() is not having f_frsize.

Comment: Quick search online for you showed [this result](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/17235/os.statvfs_result) which serves as an example on how to construct a real object, but given that you are only using a couple attributes from `result`, you may wish to create a mock class of that and supply that as the `return_value` for `patch`.

Comment: @metatoaster thanks for the pointer, I tried return_value=os.statvfs_result(4096, 0, 1000, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) looks like it will work. Giving a couple of more tries, will update soon.

Comment: @metatoaster using return_value=os.statvfs_result((4096, 4096, 1909350, 1491513, 1394521, 971520, 883302, 883302, 0, 255)) worked. Thanks. You can update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below function

```
@patch('os.statvfs', return_value=os.statvfs_result((4096, 4096, 1909350, 1491513, 1394521, 971520, 883302, 883302, 0, 255)))
def test_disk_space(self, os_statvfs):
    something
    something
```

The values are corresponding to below fields so change it accrodingly. Also, note that values should be inside double braces.

```
posix.statvfs_result(f_bsize=4096, f_frsize=4096, f_blocks=1909350L, f_bfree=1491513L,
f_bavail=1394521L, f_files=971520L, f_ffree=883302L, f_fvail=883302L, f_flag=0,
f_namemax=255)
```